# Quickest way to generate out 64 to the 5th power character codes and then randomly order them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Okay, this is a pretty interesting piece that I am working on, and at the end, I want to have some 1,073,741,824 unique five digit character codes but randomly ordered.

Essentially, I have 64 ascii characters in a table (one field of char(1)) which is case sensitive.  What I want to do is generate out the total combinations and then randomly order them, or get a way to randomly access and mark them off.

I think that I have a way to do the latter in my head (keep a running total of the number left in another table, use that as the random seed, select one and then delete it from the table and then decrement that total by one).

However, I am trying to figure out the quickest way to generate out all of the five digits character codes in one feel swoop.  I am thinking that I might have to start with building up the first three characters and then running a loop to do the fourth and fifth characters.  I know that the amount of storage taken up should be 5.12GB of information in itself for the base table.

Just wondering if any other SQL gurus have a better way to do it.

Comment: Why did you answer your own question _twice_ without even giving the community sufficient time to reply?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `CROSS JOIN` your single character table 4 times (once for each additional character past the first), and then order the records randomly:

```
SELECT t1.field + t2.field + t3.field + t4.field + t5.field AS code
FROM yourTable t1 CROSS JOIN
     yourTable t2 CROSS JOIN
     yourTable t3 CROSS JOIN
     yourTable t4 CROSS JOIN
     yourTable t5
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Beaten to the punch :) Full working example here: https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/c7b47c0df5cd21ebc8210173edee41d0

Answer (score 0):

By looping, I was meaning taking x rows from the base character table and then doing a cross join, this way it would be working with smaller recordsets.

See, if I already had 3 digit codes, and 64 characters, I could do something like

```
declare @x int = 1, @low int = 8 

while @low <= 64
begin
    insert into [4char table name] 
    select x.C + a.Code
    FROM base3codes a CROSS JOIN
    (select C from basec WHERE CID BETWEEN @x AND @low) as x

    select @x = @x + 8, @low = @low + 8
end
```

Then do the same at the five character length level.  I think this would run a lot quicker

Comment: Simply try both variations (and report results).